# Passar objeto por Ajax

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Gostaria de saber como consigo através de uma requisição ajax, trazer para meu site uma lista de elementos, onde esses elementos são linhas de uma consulta sql.
Exemplificando, tenho uma tabela de funcionários. No formulário, quando o usuário escolher uma área, deve preencher em um campo 'select' todos os funcionários daquela área. Meu código retorna apenas 'undefined'

```
function buscaNome(area)
{
$("#nomeEsp").empty();  

$.ajax({

url: 'php/buscaNomes.php',
type: 'POST',
async: true,
dataType: 'json',
data: {'especialidade':especialidade},         

success: function(result) {


if (result != "")
{                  
    var campoSelect = document.getElementById("nomeEsp");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = result[0].nome;
    option.value = result[0].nome;
    campoSelect.add(option);

 }
},

error: function(xhr, status, error) {
alert(status + error + xhr.responseText);
}

});  

}
```

Código q faz a consulta:

```
class Medico 
{
public $nome;

}

try
{
require "conexaoMysql.php";
$listaMedico = "";
$listaMedico = array();

if (isset($_POST["especialidade"]))
$especialidade = $_POST["especialidade"];

$sql = "
    SELECT Nome
    FROM funcionario
    WHERE Especialidade = '$especialidade';
";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($nome);

while($stmt->fetch()){
    $medico = new Medico();

    $medico->nome = $nome;

    $listaMedico[] = $medico;
 }

 $jsonStr = json_encode($listaMedico);
 echo $jsonStr;

 }
 catch (Exception $e)
 {
 $msgErro = $e->getMessage();
 }


 if ($conn != null)
 $conn->close();

 ?>
```

Obs: Eu coloquei result[0].nome apenas para teste, na teoria deveria criar um for

Comment: O seu `$jsonStr` tem os resultados corretos?

Comment: Sim, só não consigo listar todos os resultados, esta aparecendo só o primeiro nome, havia dito que estava aparecendo undefined, mas não. Está aparecendo apenas a primeira linha da consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa amigo tudo bem ?

Faça o seguinte:

//Na classe médico cria um método que transforma o Objeto em Json

```
class Medico 
{
    public $nome;

    public function JsonRetorno()
    {
        return json_encode(get_object_vars($this));
    }
}
```

//Em vez de um array de Objetos crie um array de json

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $medico = new Medico();

    $medico->nome = $nome;

    $listaMedico[] = $medico->JsonRetorno();
 }
```

//Para printar o código

```
 $jsonStr = json_encode($listaMedico);
 echo $jsonStr;
```

Programei um código parecido para teste e deu tudo certo:
//Classe médico

```
Class Medico
{
    private  $nome;
    private  $login;
    private  $senha;

    public function setNome($nome)
    {
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }

    public function setLogin($login)
    {
        $this->login  = $login;
    }

    public function setSenha($senha)
    {
        $this->senha = $senha;
    }

    public function JsonRetorno()
    {
        return json_encode(get_object_vars($this));
    }
}
```

//Classe Main

```
include("Medico.php");

Class Main
{
    function __construct()
    {

        $medicos = [];
        $medico = new Medico();
        $medico->setNome("Vinicius");
        $medico->setLogin("AnjoNegro");
        $medico->setSenha("StackOverFlow");

        $medicos[] = $medico->JsonRetorno(); //Adiciona médico para array Json 

        $medico2 = new Medico();
        $medico2->setNome("Vinicius2");
        $medico2->setLogin("AnjoNegro2");
        $medico2->setSenha("StackOverFlow2");
        $medicos[] = $medico2->JsonRetorno();

        echo json_encode($medicos);

    }
}

$objMain = new Main();
```

//Um exemplo de captura de Json no html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://zeptojs.com/zepto.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script>
        $.getJSON("main.php", function(data) {
            $("html").html(data);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]